# No boot after uninstalling ubuntu 12.04 with ubuntu uninstaller

Tags: 12.04, uefi

Install ubuntu 12.04 on a recent ASUS with UEFI BIOS. 
Uninstall ubuntu with UBUNTU uninstaller (OS-Uninstaller from  liveCD Ubuntu)
The next boot after uninstall gives grub rescue which does not accept many useful commands.

What can I do to restore the MBR to boot from windows knowing that I cannot enter the BIOS UEFI anymore, it stays on the grub rescue. 
How can I get back to the BIOS UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

To install a Microsoft style MBR, boot from Ubuntu LiveCD/USB. Open the terminal and run the following cmds:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk -e universe && sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install mbr
sudo install-mbr /dev/sda
```

Please change the device type sda or hda as per your system in the last cmd.

Comment: If the computer is booting Windows in UEFI mode, this won't work, and could actually cause additional problems on some systems. It's unclear from the original post if Windows wants to boot in BIOS/legacy or UEFI mode, though.

Answer (score 0):

Boot up Windows install DVD, choose

> Repair your Computer

open command prompt
Run Following command

```
bootrec.exe/fixboot
```

next

```
bootrec.exe/fixmbr
```

Answer (score 0):

Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) --> Advanced options --> untick "`Backup and rename EFI files`" --> tick "`Restore EFI backups`" --> Apply . If any problem, indicate the URL that will appear.